# R For loop unwanted overwrite

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest

I would like every result of the loop in a different text(somename).

Right now the loop overwrites;

```
library(rvest)

main.page <- read_html(x = "http://www.imdb.com/event/ev0000681/2016")
urls <- main.page %>% # feed `main.page` to the next step
    html_nodes(".alt:nth-child(2) strong a") %>% # get the CSS nodes
    html_attr("href") # extract the URLs


for (i in urls){
    a01 <- paste0("http://www.imdb.com",i)
    text <- read_html(a01) %>% # load the page
            html_nodes(".credit_summary_item~ .credit_summary_item+ .credit_summary_item .itemprop , .summary_text+ .credit_summary_item .itemprop") %>% # isloate the text
            html_text()
}
```

How could I code it in such a way that the 'i'  from the list is added tot text in the for statement?

Comment: you need an empty list before the `for` to store that `text` in its respective index

Comment: but then I only get the result of the last input of the i list in text

Comment: Have you tried `texts <- sapply(urls, function(i) { ... })`? (**edit**: should use `lapply` instead, keep each element completely encased in a list element.)

Comment: Sorry I do not understand how I could make this work. Where do I put the for loop in this?

Comment: You don't. One of the purposes/benefits of using one of the `*apply` functions: each element of `urls` is processed (as `i` in this example) in the expression; the last value of that expression is stored in a vector (`sapply`, usually) or list (`lapply`, always), easily gathering all of your results into one compact variable. Give it a try, then run `str(texts)` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solidify my comment:

```
main.page <- read_html(x = "http://www.imdb.com/event/ev0000681/2016")
urls <- main.page %>% # feed `main.page` to the next step
    html_nodes(".alt:nth-child(2) strong a") %>% # get the CSS nodes
    html_attr("href") # extract the URLs

texts <- sapply(head(urls, n = 3), function(i) {
  read_html(paste0("http://www.imdb.com", i)) %>%
    html_nodes(".credit_summary_item~ .credit_summary_item+ .credit_summary_item .itemprop , .summary_text+ .credit_summary_item .itemprop") %>%
    html_text()
  }, simplify = FALSE)
str(texts)
# List of 3
#  $ /title/tt5843990/: chr [1:4] "Lav Diaz" "Charo Santos-Concio" "John Lloyd Cruz" "Michael De Mesa"
#  $ /title/tt4551318/: chr [1:4] "Andrey Konchalovskiy" "Yuliya Vysotskaya" "Peter Kurth" "Philippe Duquesne"
#  $ /title/tt4550098/: chr [1:4] "Tom Ford" "Amy Adams" "Jake Gyllenhaal" "Michael Shannon"
```

If you use `lapply(...)`, you'll get an *unnamed* list, which may or may not be a problem for you. Instead, using `sapply(..., simplify = FALSE)`, we get a *named* list where each name is (in this case) the partial url retrieved from `urls`.

Using `sapply` without `simplify` can lead to unexpected outputs. As an example:

```
set.seed(9)
sapply(1:3, function(i) rep(i, sample(3, size=1)))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

One may think that this will *always* return a vector. However, if any of the single elements returned is not the same length (for instance) as the others, then the vector becomes a list:

```
set.seed(10)
sapply(1:3, function(i) rep(i, sample(3, size=1)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 3
```

In which case, it's best to have certainty in the return value, forcing a list:

```
set.seed(9)
sapply(1:3, function(i) rep(i, sample(3, size=1)), simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

That way, you always know exactly how to reference sub-returns. (This is one of the tenets and advantages to Hadley's [`purrr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html) package: each function always returns a list of exactly the type you declare. (There are other advantages to the package.)